# Why do subtypes need to be assigned to a variable before being used as a function argument?

Tags: typescript, subtyping

I'm learning about subtypes and am wondering why an example given here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html compiles, but when I pass the subtype directly as an argument to a function, it does not compile.

Here's the original code from typescriptlang.org

```
interface Named {
    name: string;
}

let x: Named;
// y's inferred type is { name: string; location: string; }
let y = { name: "Alice", location: "Seattle" };


function greet(n: Named) {
    console.log("Hello, " + n.name);
}
greet(y); // OK
```

That compiles fine. But this version, where the subtype is not assigned to y, fails.

```
interface Named {
    name: string;
}

let x: Named;

function greet(n: Named) {
    console.log("Hello, " + n.name);
}
greet({ name: "Alice", location: "Seattle" }); // NOT OK
```

I get the error:

Argument of type '{ name: string; location: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Named'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'location' does not exist in type 'Named'.

Why is it that the subtype { name: "Alice", location: "Seattle" } has to be assigned to a variable first?

Comment: It's called excess property checks, it's triggered only when you assign a fresh object literal to  the parameter of a given type.

Comment: Titian Cernicova-Dragomir already gave you the answer, but you should check out the official documentation for a deeper explanation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Also, there's another option if you don't want to use a variable:

greet({ name: "Alice", location: "Seattle" } as Named);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you use a "fresh" object literal (meaning one that hasn't been assigned to a variable yet) in a place that expects a particular type, it's *often* an error to add properties not mentioned in the type.  So this is flagged as an error via [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks).  It's one of the few places where a type is treated as "closed" or "exact" (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936) as opposed to "open".

There are workarounds in the case where you don't mean for excess property checks to happen.  One is to add an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) to the type of the `n` parameter so that all extra properties are acceptable:

```
function greet(n: Named & { [x: string]: unknown }) {
  console.log("Hello, " + n.name);
}
greet({ name: "Alice", location: "Seattle" }); // okay
```

Or, if you usually want such checking but just want to call `greet()` with that particular object literal, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to avoid intermediate variables:

```
greet({ name: "Alice", location: "Seattle" } as Named); // okay
```

It's up to you.

Comment: Really strange that assigning the object to another variable bypasses the check.

Comment: You can read the [original pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3823) detailing how this works.  Looks like the intent is that extra properties should be caught and not silently discarded.  If you assign to another variable, the inferred type of that variable will have the extra property.  After that if you pass it to something expecting a wider type, they assume you meant to do it.