# Why is the error different between subtype assignments and regular assignments?

Tags: typescript

sample code is below, I am checked by TypeScript playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

```
interface PartialCustomData {
    option?: number;
}

interface A {
    [key: string]: string | PartialCustomData;
}

interface B extends A {
    [key: string]: string | PartialCustomData | {[key: string]: string};
}

// this is no error
const b: B = { key1: 'a', key2: {b: 'b'}};
const a: A = b;

// this is error
const _a: A = { key1: 'a', key2: {b: 'b'}}
```

in this case, `const a: A = b;` is no error.
but `const _a: A = { key1: 'a', key2: {b: 'b'}}` is error.

error is below

```
Type '{ b: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | PartialCustomData'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'b' does not exist in type 'PartialCustomData'.(2322)
input.ts(6, 5): The expected type comes from this index signature.
```

Why doesn't error occur at `const a: A = b;`?

Comment: Read about [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) and [the PR that implemented it](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3823).  Excess properties are only an error on "fresh" object literals.  Assigning to an intervening variable loses that "freshness".

Comment: Duplicate of [Why do subtypes need to be assigned to a variable before being used as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56007522/why-do-subtypes-need-to-be-assigned-to-a-variable-before-being-used-as-a-functio)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `{[key: string]: string}` is assignable to `PartialCustomData` as an empty object `{}` (it fits `{option?: number}`) and typescript considers them as the same type.

Long story short - it's a bug of typescript.

With `option` it would be a better example

```
// this is no error
const b: B = { key1: 'a', key2: {option: 'b'}}; // works
const a: A = b;

// this is error
const _a: A = { key1: 'a', key2: {option: 'b'}}; // fails
```