# Typescript: structural typing check has inconsistence behaviour

Tags: typescript

TypeScript uses [structural typing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing), as such two types are compatible if their members are compatible:

```
class Point2D {
  x: number = 1
  y: number = 2
}

class Point3D {
  x: number = 1
  y: number = 2
  z: number = 3
}

function iTake2D(p:Point2D) { /* do something */ }

const threeD:Point3D = new Point3D()

iTake2D(threeD)         // okay
iTake2D(new Point3D())  // okay
```

However, in the example bellow structural type checking seems to fail:

```
interface Point2D {
  x: number
  y: number
}

interface Point3D {
  x: number
  y: number
  z: number
}

function iTake2D(p:Point2D) { /* do something */ }

const threeD:Point3D =  { x: 1, y: 3, z: 1 }

iTake2D(threeD)                // okay
iTake2D({ x: 1, y: 3, z: 1 })  // Not okay!
                   // ^^^^
                   // [tsserver 2345] [E] Argument of type '{ x: number; y: number; z: number; }'
                   //  is not assignable to parameter of type 'Point2D'.
                   //    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'z' does not exist in
                   // type 'Point2D'.
```

What am I missing? Please help!

Here are the Typescript playground links to the above two examples:
([link-to-eg-1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKD2BLAdgFwEwBFoG8CwAUNNAB4Bc0yArgLYBGApgE7QC80AjIcQJ4XX1mbaOkIBfQoVCQYCFKgDM2fEVL9ajFuy6q%20lDUPajVAL3WCt0BeMkEAZlWTBUieMmiIAKmADWDLAAUAA5kcmhYAJS40AD0AFTQACbw0BDwNAyoABYoAObQcTHQEgRSbhCo0NlMDAyYoUhoSsLIDADucI2KmAERtl6%20-j3VtZhRxBMTMUXwPmA8hAN%20ga0dYd2949PQs-OEQA)), ([link-to-eg-2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoHtRgEwBFkDeAsAFDLIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtKeQJ433OskC+pUlmjwkaTOADM+YmUpdGLKG2Sdai3uQBeCnsv6CSMOiARhg6EMmAAVOAGsIeABQAHKhix4AlIWQB6ACpkABN0ZABndAYIMAALUABzZED-ZAESUgRLCLBkeKgICFwPCTBpZABecgJ5ZABGABpVGklmnQb0w1sHJ1xnAqLcX3JRsfGAtPR7OHYhO0cXWuoG5rU25A769JH-NIA5dDzp2YBCFQnLsb3kAD1724urq5uAbTAIiOgAN2hkbEkABYAKwAXWQrwAouCAIJQRKMCDgZDoGD5diuFAAcmWuiUAG4Wuo9ISOtwCeksU9nhMbtYIrQjsg4J9gIkQHAmAAbFBgcKuOBQOAxSBQFFosAY7GecB4LEAOmpNOuaVGAHkmAArCBmZBc4CiuBc5AMWYokBc9iRTEIYAwK32EDoADuVlcUHQmKg5ggEWacBAIWQWK0WNC6F9jLyEAowFy1hASuV5BuksxwZlOFwCsMpCAA))

Comment: this works: `iTake2D({ x: 1, y: 3, z: 1 } as Point3D)`

Comment: @Daniel Kaplan, that does not explain why `iTake2D(threeD)` is okay (no casting required).

Comment: TypeScript performs [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) on *object literals*.  For more information, see [microsoft/TypeScript#3823](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3823) for the implementation and reasoning, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56007522/why-do-subtypes-need-to-be-assigned-to-a-variable-before-being-used-as-a-functio) to a similar question.  Or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68478837/2887218) to the reverse question.

Comment: That's why I said it as a comment instead of an answer.